# MPC-HC enable OSD with audio

Tags: windows-7, windows, osd

I use
[MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.org), and if you are watching a video and you

- Play
- Pause
- Seek
- Change Volume
- etc

a nice OSD shows you that information. However if you are playing an audio file, nothing. How do you get the OSD with audio files as well?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how your MPC-HC looks when playing an audio file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to
[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net).

It does all of this and more.